# A fresh perspective confusion about a paragraph

Tags: rendering, perspective, camera-matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to re-implement the paper ["A fresh perspective"](https://www.dgp.toronto.edu/%7Ekaran/pdf/perspective.pdf)

In this paper there is one paragraph on secion 2 that reads:

> Usually, $z_s = z$
> is the depth value of the point $P$, unchanged by $V_i$
> . We
> extend the viewport transformations $V_i$ so that the cannonical depth of a point $z ∈ [0, 1] $ is linearly mapped to
> $z_s$ in an arbitrary, user specified range. While the relative depth values are preserved with respect to a single
> perspective view, this allows the powerful visual capability of intuitively altering the relative depths of points in
> a scene as one transitions between the mutiple linear perspectives.

I think I am not fully understanding the explanation.

If $z_s = z$ what does it mean that "the cannonical depth of a point $z ∈ [0, 1] $ is linearly mapped to
$z_s$"?

We have $(x, y, z) = PM_i$, which I am assuming is the orthogonal normalization of space into the classic rendering box $[-1,1]^2\times [0, 1]$.

So $z$ is the depth before perspective and $z_s$ after perspective I think.

What exactly is the linear mapping described in the paper? I am very lost.